# What do designers do when a new Apple Components Library comes out?

Tags: ios, apple, component, library, hig

I'm using the newest iOS and MacOS Components Libraries for Sketch that I downloaded from the Apple HIG site.
There are some components that either don't make sense or there is a part of the component that is missing or not consistent so I have to make a custom library in my files to support Apple's one.

My question is:

When a new version of the Sketch Apple Component Library gets released, (maybe iOS 14 for example) what will we do with our iOS 13 library? Will we use both at once? Start using iOS 14 library exclusively?
What happens to components that I make as custom ones? Will the custom components get pushed around if apple changes the size of their table cell for example?

Will my current iOS13 components get over written by the iOS 14 ones?

What have you designers done in the past moving up to iOS13 ?

Thank you

Comment: May I ask if you are using any additional libraries in combination with one by Apple? E.g. you might have additional components like checkbox/radio button

Answer (score 0):

There are many answers to this question. What I do is I listen to the users and keep up with them. I watch the analytics and see how many of them have upgraded the iOS version. If there is a massive shift towards the newer version, I start designing and testing the new HIG elements. If the users don't rush towards the upgrade I will keep the current HIG.

Once the vast majority of the users have upgraded then I make sure to push the new design. I don't want my apps to look outdated.

Then of course us UX designers are not the sole decision makers and we need to talk with the other stakeholders, be mindful of constraints and then move forward.